# Как разместить на 1 странице несколько слайдеров Swiper?

Tags: javascript, swiper

Как разместить на 1 странице несколько независимых слайдеров Swiper?

Comment: а в чем проблема по рефам сделать

Comment: @AndreyFreiz В том что крутить в самой докментации до сюдого очень долго :) https://swiperjs.com/demos#multiple-swipers

Comment: Документацию я покрутил, дело было в пропущенной точке которую я долго не мог найти.